# How can I use multiple values in a "where" clause?

Tags: php, mysql

My code and my database are the following

```
$my=mysql_query("select * from users where email='ids'")or die(mysql_error);

id___email___________pass
1    abc@d.com        123
2    xxx@x.uk         333
3    ah@cc.com        555
```

I need a syntax in which I will `select * where id='1 , 3'` and when I will echo $row[email] it will return

```
abc@d.com
ah@cc.com
```

---

Found the correct syntax:

```
$all=mysql_query("select * from users where id IN ('1','2','3')");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($all))
{
   echo $row['name'];
}
```

Comment: use mysqli or PDO mysql_query is deprecated

Comment: This looks terrifyingly insecure. Are you **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php)? `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Answer (score 4):

Use `IN` clause to get records for multiple emails.

```
$my=mysql_query("select * from users where email IN ('$email','$email2','$email3')")
or die(mysql_error);
```

Comment: I'll add that you can also string WHERE clauses together using AND and OR.

Comment: @AGreenman - you can; but for this case, using an IN clause makes the code easier to read and to maintain.

Comment: i have a string wich is $string = " 1,2,3,4,5,6 "; , so the mysql querry will select from all the numbers in the string

Comment: @andrewsi - Yes, I agree. I was just adding on to his answer in case Alex Bonta wasn't aware.

Comment: @AlexBonta: you can use same logic for `email` or `numbers`, as long as you are using `IN` clause

Comment: but note that `WHERE foo IN ('a,b,c')` is **NOT** the same as `foo IN ('a', 'b', 'c')` and NOT the same as `foo IN (a, b, c)`

Comment: No you didnt understand!  i have 2 rows in my database
1 | First Title | First content and 2 | Second Title| Second content

With that select i want to select where id = 1,2 instead of using AND , so when i echo a $row[title]; will echo the both titles

Comment: @AlexBonta: you can not use it like that. that's not the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Another, not optimal, solution is adding several options to the "where" clause.

Uses more resources, but, sometimes, is what you need.

By the way, I strongly, suggest put you SQL in a variable, first.

```
$myquery  = "select * from users ";
$myquery .= "where (1 = 0) "; // defaults to false
$myquery .= "or  (email='$email') "; // maybe true
$myquery .= "or  (email='$email2') "; // maybe true
$myquery .= "or  (email='$email3') "; // maybe true

$mydataset = mysql_query($myquery) or die(mysql_error);
```

There multiple "or" expression with a "=" string comparison, are the non optimal, more resources used, equivalent of the "in" operator.

Yet, sometimes is useful to know, or use, this equivalent. If you are not sure if the source string is case sensitive, or you want to trim the value for unwanted spaces, you could also replace the "=" operator by the "like" operator.

```
$email  = trim($email);
$email2 = trim($email2);
$email3 = trim($email3);

$myquery  = "select * from users ";
$myquery .= "where (1 = 0) "; // defaults to false
$myquery .= "or  (email like '%$email%') "; // maybe true
$myquery .= "or  (email like '%$email2%') "; // maybe true
$myquery .= "or  (email like '%$email3%') "; // maybe true

$mydataset = mysql_query($myquery) or die(mysql_error);
```

Cheers.

Comment: It's worth noting that the `or die` pattern should die. It can expose sensitive information about your system configuration.

Comment: @tadman agree. My example maintains the "or die" from the original example.